# Pushing only certain code to different repositories

Tags: git, codeigniter, bitbucket, gitlab-ci

I have a Codeigniter project that needs two different repos: one for local development with my team (bitbucket) and one on my client's side for deployment (gitlab). I am looking for ways to simplify getting changes from one repo to the other.

My issue: For local development, I need files which I don't want to push to the clients server (composer, package.json, ...) and vice versa (deploy.php, yml files from gitlab-ci), but the majority of the files is the same and only changed by me and my team.

From what I have read, simply adding a second git-remote wouldn't work because I couldn't have two gitignore files. I have never worked with git submodules, but from what I understand, it would require subfolders and the files that differ between the repos need to be in the root directory. Have I understood this correctly?

Is there a way to push only certain files in certain directions/remote repos?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to push only certain files in certain directions/remote repos?

No.  But you're starting from an incorrect supposition: that Git pushes *files*.  It doesn't.  Git does not store *files* at all, really.  Instead, Git stores *commits*.  Each commit:

- is numbered, with a unique hash ID;
- contains two things: a full snapshot of *every* file, and some metadata.

Each commit therefore stores files, but what you transfer with `git push` is not individual files, but rather entire commits.

A *repository* is, at its heart, just two databases:

- The first and usually largest database contains the commits and other supporting objects.  Typically you pick one particular commit—using its hash ID, but see the next point—and "check it out" with `git checkout`, or "switch" to it with `git switch`.  This extracts *all* the files *from* that particular commit, and *now* you have files.  But until you do this step, all you have are the commits.  Well, the commits, the supporting objects, and...
- The second database contains *names:* branch names, tag names, and various other names.  Each of these names holds a hash ID; branch names in particular always hold *commit* hash IDs (some names can and sometimes do hold hash IDs of supporting objects, which then lead to usable commits).

If you have two repositories, you simply have two of these pairs of databases.  If you wish to set up an area in which you have files that are *extracted from* two different commits in two different repositories, but into a single mingled-together area, you can do that, but that is not something that *Git* is good at.  Git "likes" for the working area to contain the files from *one commit in one repository*.  That way any changes you make can be stored into a *new* commit in that (one) repository with a simple `git add` and `git commit`.  Don't use Git itself to mash two sets of files together.  Instead, set up the two separate Git repositories, work in them separately, and use some additional software you obtain or write, to read the two separate Git work areas (or individual commits directly out of the two repositories) and mash them together with whatever rules you like.

This may get complicated.  Consider, e.g., that you will need to decide what to do when snapshot L, on the left, contains files `A`, `B`, and `C/D`, and snapshot R, on the right, contains files `B`, `F`, and `C`.  Only one of the two versions of `B` can appear in the mashed-together location.  And, if *file* `C` is to appear in the mashed-together location, you probably cannot also have a *folder* `C` containing a file `D`.  (This kind of complication is part of why Git does not do this.)